# How to count listbox items From Index 10 to 20?

Tags: vb.net-2010

My Question is ???
- How to count "listbox" items from index
10 to 20 ...  like this =>
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

but not like this one 
0 1 2 3 4 ......20

### - M Using this code but not achieved ....

For Index As integer = CInt(listbox1.items.count = 10) To 20 
next

### As Well this one but same prome ..

For  Index As integer = 10 To Listbox1.items.count 20
next

---

index is always running from 0 to 20 but not from 10 to 20 ....

i m stuck over here, can one one plzz tell me what m doing wrong within above given code ....

need help ...
thnxxs

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are having a syntax problem, because you write a value to listbox1.items.count while you are in a read context.

The [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) states:

```
For index As Integer = 1 To 5
```

In order to make your code work, try:

```
For index As Integer = CInt(listbox1.items.count) To 20
```

The count should start at anything between 0 and 20. In your case the variable should have the value 10. Make sure the variable has that value before running the For-loop.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved Your Problem :)

Here Is How Your Form Should Look Like:

[image]

and here is the Code :

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Index As Integer = CInt(ListBox1.Items.Item(8)) To 20
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & Index & vbLf
        Next
    End Sub

    'You can also use this code...

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim X As Integer = 8
        While X < 19
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & ListBox1.Items.Item(X) & vbLf
            X += 1
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

I hope this code was useful to you. :)

Comment: thnxxs guys but i have done it by myself ... there was a minor change that i have done and sry i didn't checked yur code but thnxxs for the answer ... hope this codes will usefull to someother guys ....

Comment: you welcome..... ;) [Rohit Malhotra](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4853085/rohit-malhotra)